# persistent login to unix machines

Tags: authentication, telnet, persistent

I am using putty (telnet/ssh client) to connect to hp-ux, solaris, linux server.
I remember from previous job, the support guys would login.  They would then use a command to open an old session.  They ran jobs that required a long time, using this method.  If their putty session died, the persistent login screen could be reached after disconnection.  Does anyone know the command?

Thanks.

edit:  You're right.  It was screen.  But my machines don't seem to have it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might be talking about [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). This command allows one to detach from a console session running on a remote machine, log out, and leave the session running. One can then log back in to the remote machine and reattach. There is also an X equivalent of screen called [xpra](http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra), which allows on to do a similar thing, but with X applications. There is also [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), with similar functionality to GNU Screen, but under a BSD license (GNU Screen is licensed under the GPL).

Comment: @totaam: Thanks for the link. I last tried xpra 0.0.6, which didn't work for me. Perhaps this version will work better.